# Independent events vs. independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Suppose we have a random experiment that involves tossing three coins at once. Our sample space is the pair: the triple of faces that show and the average speed with which the coins land. Thus
$$
\Omega = \{\omega_j\} = \{ \{face, face, face \}_j, \; avg. \, speed_j \}.
$$
Suppose $\omega_5 = \{ \{H,T,T\}, 2.4 m/s \}$, and $\omega_7 = \{ \{H,H,H\}, 1.9 m/s \}$.
While these are outcomes they are also events. We say that they are independent if
$P(\omega_5 \cap \ \omega_7) = P(\omega_5)P(\omega_7)$. Let us say that is true. (I realize one or both probabilities must be zero but that is not material.)

I think I am on solid ground so far.

Suppose now we define two RVs, $X$, which returns the head count, and $Y$, which returns the  speed. Then
$$
(X(\omega_5),Y(\omega_5)) = (1,2.4) \; \text{ and } \; (X(\omega_7),Y(\omega_7)) = (3,1.9). 
$$
I think I'm correct in saying that the independence of $\omega_5$ and $\omega_7$ says nothing
about the independence of $X$ and $Y$. I ask this because I've read in several places that
the RVs can only be independent if the events they map to $\mathbb{R}$ are independent. This troubles
me because the independence of events is an "inter-event" concept whereas the RVs
in question are associated with the same event (outcome) so it is an "intra-event" concept.

However, we also have that $X$ and $Y$ are only independent if $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ are independent, which seems to point back to the event space.

I'd appreciate some clear-headed thinking on this as I seem to have wound myself into knots.

Comment: Outcomes are not events, you can't even write probability of an outcome (the closest thing is to take an event consisting of this outcome and take its probability). RVs are not associated with outcomes, they are functions on the sample space. RVs $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff any event definable using $X$ is independent of any event definable using $Y$. I think the best start to reduce confusion will be to review definitions of probability space, random variable and independence, and check how your example fits into them.

Comment: @mihaild. Thank you for weighing in. You've answered the question directly. I realize I should have made the second dimension countable too instead of continuous. Everything I've read says that probabilities are assigned to outcomes in countable sample spaces (or $\sigma$-algebras, if you like). That's what I was aiming for but screwed it up.